# Make the basis of a function from nest loop outer components

Tags: matlab, function, loops, dry

I have a segment of code where a composition of nested loops needs to be run at various times; however, each time the operations within the nested loops are different. Is there a way to make the outer portion (loop composition) somehow a functional piece, so that the internal operations are variable. For example, below, two code blocks are shown which both use the same loop introduction, but have different purposes. According to the principle of DRY, how can I improve this, so as not to need to repeat myself each time a similar loop needs to be used?

```
% BLOCK 1
for a = 0:max(aVec)
  for p = find(aVec'==a)
    iDval = iDauVec{p};

    switch numel(iDval)
      case 2
        r = rEqVec(iDval);
        qVec(iDval(1)) = qVec(p) * (r(2)^0.5 / (r(1)^0.5 + r(2)^0.5));
        qVec(iDval(2)) = qVec(p) - qVec(iDval(1));
      case 1
        qVec(iDval) = qVec(p);
    end

  end
end

% BLOCK 2
for gen = 0:max(genVec)-1
  for p = find(genVec'==gen)
    iDval = iDauVec{p};

    QinitVec(iDval) = QinitVec(p)/numel(iDval);

  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write your loop structure as a function, which takes a function handle as one of its inputs. Within the loop structure, you can call this function to carry out your operation.

It looks as if the code inside the loop needs the values of `p` and `iDval`, and needs to assign to different elements of a vector variable in the workspace. In that case a suitable function definition might be something like this:

```
function vec = applyFunctionInLoop(aVec, vec, iDauVec, funcToApply)
for a = 0:max(aVec)
    for p = find(aVec'==a)
        iDval = iDauVec{p};
        vec = funcToApply(vec, iDval, p);
    end
end
end
```

You would need to put the code for each different operation you want to carry out in this way into a function with suitable input and output arguments:

```
function qvec = myFunc1(qVec, iDval, p)
    switch numel(iDval)
        case 2
            r = rEqVec(iDval); % see note
            qVec(iDval(1)) = qVec(p) * (r(2)^0.5 / (r(1)^0.5 + r(2)^0.5));
            qVec(iDval(2)) = qVec(p) - qVec(iDval(1));
        case 1
            qVec(iDval) = qVec(p);
    end
end

function v = myFunc2(v, ix, q)
    v(ix) = v(q)/numel(ix);
end
```

Now you can use your loop structure to apply each function:

```
qvec = applyFunctionInLoop(aVec, qVec, iDauVec, myFunc1);

QinitVec = applyFunctionInLoop(aVec, QinitVec, iDauVec, myFunc2);
```

and so on.

In most of the answer I've kept to the same variable names you used in your question, but in the definition of `myFunc2` I've changed the names to emphasise that these variables are local to the function definition - the function is not operating on the *variables* you passed in to it, but on the *values* of those variables, which is why we have to pass the final value of the vector out again.

Note that if you want to use the values of other variables in your functions, such as `rEqVec` in `myFunc1`, you need to think about whether those variables will be available in the function's workspace. I recommend reading these help pages on the Mathworks site:

[Share Data Between Workspaces](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/share-data-between-workspaces.html)

[Dynamic Function Creation with Anonymous and Nested Functions](https://uk.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/dynamic-function-creation-with-anonymous-and-nested-functions.html?s_tid=srchtitle)